# Pass textbox variables to query Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sheets

I'm designing a "SIMPLE" web app, I want to query the sheet using the user's response( captured in the html textbox) and then display the cells that match in the HTML page, but the issue is wiring the submit button to return the results

```
function doGet(e) {
   return HtmlService
   .createTemplateFromFile('frontend')
   .evaluate()
   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
 }
```

And in the html I have basically

```
   <tr>
     <td>Search name: </td>
     <td><input type="text" name="Name" /></td>
   </tr>
   <input type="submit" onclick="google.script.run.do_it(??????)">
```

How do I send the textbox variables to Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

The input needs to be inside a form, and then you pass the form text input as this.parentNode (it's an object)

```
    <form id="myForm">

    <table>  

    <tr><td>First Name</td><td><input type="textbox" size="100" name="first" required> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input type="textbox" size="100" name="last" required> </td></tr>
    </table>
    <br><br>
<input type="button" id="load" value="Start" onclick="inputForm(this.parentNode)"  
          style="padding:5px;color: #fff; border-color: white;"/>

    </form>
```

inside the function you pass the form to, you can access the variables in the object like this

```
inputForm(e){
Logger.log(e.first);
Logger.log(e.last);
}
```

Does that give you enough to get started?

Comment: Hi yes thanks, the fix I’m in is how to output in html the results of what last names match in a certain column of the sheet(which I can figure that part out). You can’t output in the .gs part of the web app

Comment: So after doing the computation, I need a way to display the results of the computation.

Comment: Any ideas on this? appreciated